# .htaccess, codeigniter dont load images

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter with absolute paths. My images, and css are in css, img folders, I  use the following code to hide the index.php. CSS are working fine, but images via img tag doesnt load. It is strange but using css with url() it does load.  Whats wrong with the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|eot|svg|ttf|png|jpg|images|stylesheets|favicon.ico|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteBase /

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Options All -Indexes
```

```
# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

My .htaccess file content it is working like a monster. Can you try it ?

Comment: Hey Serkan, thanx. My default controller is named Jindex.php and points to view vindex.php,  what change is needed? "# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this"